# Using lapply in data.table to extract element from a list column

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, summary

I merged a list of lm summaries with a data.table.
Next, I extract a coefficient from the summaries and generate a new column containing the number.
My question is, why do I have to use lapply to complete such work?
For example, the following code worked.

```
new.DT <- old.DT[, result := lapply(X = results.of.lm, FUN = summary)] %>%
  .[, beta := lapply(X = result, function(x) x$coefficients[2,1])]
```

While the following code failed.

```
new.DT <- old.DT[, result := lapply(X = results.of.lm, FUN = summary)] %>% 
.[, beta := result$coefficients[2,1])]
```

However, for some functions I apply to columns in data.table (e.g. paste, substr or as.numeric), lapply was not necessary.
I couldn't figure out what cause the difference. Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Re why, the column contains a list of lm summary objects. For each of them you need to separately extract with $ and [], so you use `lapply`, which loops over the objects. `paste` et al work fine on atomic vectors; see `?atomic`. For data.table all columns are either atomic or lists, so there is no special column type for working with lm summaries.

Comment: Hi Frank! I'm not sure if my understanding was correct. So, if I want to apply a function to several list subjects (e.g. .SD or a column containing many lists such as summary) inside a data.table, I will have to use ```[,var := lapply(X, FUN)]```. But if the function is applied to an atomic object, simply use ```[,var := some.function]``` will work? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that `old.DT` looks something like this:

```
   grp results.of.lm
1:   1      <lm[12]>
2:   2      <lm[12]>
3:   3      <lm[12]>
```

then, after creating the result column using `old.DT[, result:=lapply(results.of.lm,summary)]`, we note that `result` is a list of lists

```
   grp results.of.lm           result
1:   1      <lm[12]> <summary.lm[11]>
2:   2      <lm[12]> <summary.lm[11]>
3:   3      <lm[12]> <summary.lm[11]>
```

Note that old.DT$result$coefficients is NULL, and thus `beta:=result$coefficients[2,1]` will NOT return the desired result. Instead, your use of lapply does return the coefficients:

`old.DT[, beta:=lapply(result, function(x) x$coefficients[2,1])][]`

```
   grp results.of.lm           result       beta
1:   1      <lm[12]> <summary.lm[11]> -0.2819342
2:   2      <lm[12]> <summary.lm[11]>  0.1645671
3:   3      <lm[12]> <summary.lm[11]>  0.2215897
```

Comment: But what are the differences between the two methods? For example, in ```DT[, var.2 := substr(var.1, 1, 3)]```, the function ```substr``` will be applied to every element (or cell) in column var.1 right? So why couldn't ```DT[,beta:=result$coefficients[2,1]]``` work the same way, that is, applying ```$coefficients[2,1]``` to every element (which is a summary of a lm) in column ```result```?